# Select from a column which is saved in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

```
create tableA (id int(11),col varchar(30) null)

 id          col
 1           NULL
 2           NULL
 3           other_col_name
```

Now what i want to do is an `inner join` with another table. So when
the col is NULL then i'll select the **`t2.normal_col`**
if it's not null ill select the column that is inputed in the "`col`". So in this case I would select **`t2.other_col_name`**

This is what I have tried and I know that it only wil return the input in the column t1.col and not select by it.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.col, t2.normal_col) AS FROM tableA t1
INNER JOIN table2 ON t1.id= t2.id
```

How would you do?

**EDIT;**

```
table2
(
 int id,
 normal_col_name varchar(30) null, 
 other_col_name varchar(30) null,
 another_col varchar(30) null
)
```

Comment: Can't be done with regular sql.

Comment: @Kilise Have a look at my answer. I added some details.

Comment: yes, thanks i am looking! it seems good! im trying to figure out what is the best solution for me

Comment: @Kilise The view advantage is that you wouldn't have to keep two tables in sync. However it comes at a performance cost. You can also create another physical table and use triggers to keep everything up to date.

Comment: Yes I know that is what I'm thinking about, I like the idea of using the view instead of a new table, but as you said it comes a performance cost, so im still thinking about what is best for me. As i think i wont be needing that many rows in table1 so i think iwill stick to the view, but im still thinking .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done in normal design. But you can use **[EAV (entity-attribute-value)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)** design. In such a design your table2:

```
id    normal_col_name    other_col_name     another_col 
-------------------------------------------------------
1     a                  b                  c
2     d                  e                  f
```

looks like that

```
entity    attribute          value
----------------------------------
1         normal_col_name    a
1         other_col_name     b
1         another_col_name   c
2         onormal_col_name   d        
2         other_col_name     e      
2         another_col_name   f
```

Of course in such a design queries are more complicated, but what you wanted is actually quite easy:

```
select id, value
from tableA
    join EAV on id = entity and attribute = if(col is NULL, 'normal_col', col)
```

Comment: i don't save the columns in a column named attribute in the joined table

Comment: @Kilise, you must first convert the joined table (table2 you mean) to a different format, which is my table EAV. Normally the columns are named entity-attribute-value, they have of course different meaning than your original table2, because it is a different design! With your original table2 the query is not possible in regular SQL.

Comment: @Kilise, I updated my example to match yours. Maybe it's more clear now?

Comment: I do undersatnd what you mean now, I have to create a table called EAV and then enter the values to each column in an attribute in that way i will be able to reach the value. But this will make a hell of rows in the EAV table instead of columns

Comment: @Kilise Exactly. Maybe what confused you that my attribute column would match your `col` of tableA. I used the original terminology which is used in general EAV design, so that you have more general picture of the concept. It is good to know that it is EAV so you can get more help easily in the future, just by googling "EAV design".

Comment: @Kilise *"But this will make a hell of rows in the EAV table instead of columns"* - exactly. EAV design has many drawbacks you have to pay for the flexibility. The query performance is one of them.

Comment: I will use plaxl solution to this. You're solution might be better if I'had a much bigger table, but as it's not that big i'll just use a view.

Thanks for you help though now I know what EAV is and how useful it might be to use.

Answer (score 2):

The only reasonable way I see would be to write a view that would scale your schema vertically rather than horizontally for the second table. You can either create your view dynamically using table2's metadata or create it by hand. If you need a faster solution you might have to create another physical table which has that structure and keep both synchronized. You can use triggers to make sure all operations on table1 would be replicated on table1EAV.

E.g.

```
id col1 col2
------------
1  a    b
```

Would become:

```
id col  value
-------------
1  col1 a
1  col2 b
1  id   1
```

Using something like:

```
CREATE VIEW vTable2EAV
AS
SELECT id, 'id' AS col, (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE id = t.id) AS [value]
FROM table1 t
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'col1', (SELECT col1 FROM table2 WHERE id = t.id) AS [value]
FROM table1 t
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'col2', (SELECT col2 FROM table2 WHERE id = t.id) AS [value]
FROM table1 t;
```

Then your select statement would look like:

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT [value] 
        FROM vTable2EAV
        WHERE 
            id = table2.id 
            AND [col] = IFNULL(t1.col, 'normal_col')
    ) AS col_value,
    t2.some_other_t2_column
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id;
```

Comment: why is your query so complex? I think it could be much simpler, see my post

Comment: @Tomas Well I believe he also wanted to access other values in table2.

Comment: btw, display the table "vertically" just by view? I don't think that's possible, unfortunatelly...

Comment: @Tomas If you use a stored procedure that uses the table's metadata to dynamically generate the view it is ;) Definitely not efficient however.